# In what branch is specific revision?

Tags: git

I report [bug](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-11938) and it was fixed. DVCS revision attached to bug report.

I pull changes and know that it is in repo:

```
$ git show ec4e6e0
```

But when I try to update to `HEAD` or another branches I can't see this changes in fixed file.

How I can get hashes and human readable bookmarks like `origin/4.0.x` for heads which have specific revision in graph chain?

**UPDATE** I try suggestion:

```
$ git branch --contains ec4e6e0
```

and output is empty. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @nmaier Agree, this is dup.

Comment: The commit is only on a remote branch and you're not using `-a` or not tracking/fetched it?

Comment: Probably the bug was fixed but in a separate branch which hasn't already getting merged into master, or whatever branch you are tracking. You need to checkout that remote branch.

Comment: @hek2mgl Why `git show` show diff in local repo?

Comment: If I clone the Spring repository from https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework.git and then run `git branch --contains ec4e6e0`, it shows `master`.

Comment: `Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged` I think that if I resolve this issue all be ok. Thanks for help!

Comment: After `git reset --hard origin/master` - all ok!